# How to pass arguments into a Channel's queue writer?

Tags: c#, channel, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

I have a background task to be completed; however, I can't write arguments to the `Channel`. Reason being that the writer only takes in 1 argument. How do queue a function up to be completed with arguments.

```
private readonly Channel<Func<double, double, string, CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

//...

public async ValueTask QueueWorkItemAsync(
    Func<double, double, string, CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem, string args)
{
    if (workItem is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
    }

    // Can't pass args into WriteAsync
    await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
}
```

Comment: That's a problem of the implementation of the workitem Func on how to get the data to work on not one of the channel.

Comment: How would those args be used?

Comment: @StephenCleary I have a scanning service. The service needs a quick response but also has to do geolocation of the coordinates (the args) sent through, which can take a bit longer. So I am sending the geolocation task to the Queue to do the lookup with the given coordinates from a different remote service. Once retrieve I simply record the results in a local DB

Comment: I mean, there's no room for the function to take the arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up switching `Channel` for a `ConcurrentQueue`. That allowed more flexibility as to what I could put in.